# Expresiones regulares como atributos

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Las expresiones regulares todavía no se implementan bien en el navegador?
En que fallo:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/jv_13/pen/dVoBvB?editors=1010)

```html
<form method="GET" name="formu" id="formu">
   <p>
   <input type="text" name="nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]" required>
   </p>
   <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué deseas controlar con tu expresión regular? ¿Quieres permitir el ingreso de varias letras minúsculas? ¿Podrías agregar a tu pregunta ejemplos de entradas que deberían ser consideradas por la expresión regular como válidas y otros ejemplos de entradas no válidas?

Comment: es que no funcionan, no importa el patron

Comment: Abrí el link de codepen que agregaste en la pregunta y me funciona bien  en Chrome v60. En tu ejemplo estás validando el patrón de que el usuario ingrese 1 sola letra minúscula y de click en enviar, caso contrario se muestra un error indicando que el formato del texto es incorrecto.

Comment: Tal cual lo que comenta spuente, probablemente el error sea que tu patrón no se ajusta a lo que estás buscando. Además, recordá que el atributo `pattern` fue implementado en HTML5, por lo que depende en qué navegador estás probando... Estás mencionando que "falla", pero no estás describiendo cómo es que falla. Esta pregunta no puede comprenderse bien hasta que aclares (1) navegador y versión, (2) qué patrón estás intentando, y (3) qué textos deberían ser considerados válidos y cuáles inválidos.

Comment: Solo quiero que se ingresen palabras no números, solo que no funciona ni chrome ni en firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta añadir el símbolo `+`, es decir, indica al campo de entrada que acepte uno o más de los caracteres que has enumerado en la clase de caracteres `[]`.

> El patrón quedaría así: `[A-Za-z]+`

*Ejemplo:*

```html
<form method="GET" name="formu" id="formu">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Solo admite letras A-Z y a-z" required>
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

[Fuente SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287650/html5-input-validate-letters-and-numbers).